# HBase Table Creation with Pre Splitting during Sqooping

Tags: hbase, sqoop

We have a very large table and it can grow faster, say daily it can bring 10 million records in to HBase in Sqooping. I come to know if we use pre splitting while creating the table in HBase, it is very use full for faster scanning and retrieval and for updates. How to take care of pre splitting the table in HBase while doing sqooping.

I know we can achieve this by sqoping data to temporary table and then create actual table in HBase using pre splitting, then do transformation on the sqooped table and insert data into new table.

Is there any way if we can handle with out going to HBase Transformation over the table we sqooped in.

Comment: can any one help me on this?

Comment: I believe there is no option at moment, so I am planing to raise a defect for this in sqoop.